# Is there a faster way to put the result of a SQL query from Teradata into a pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, teradata

I have a SQL query from Teradata with 3 million lines and 50 columns.

I am trying to use it in python as it follows:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(tera.execute_response('''select * from table'''))
```

This process is running till my kernel dies and I lose everything.

Comment: Why does the kernel die? Could it be that you run out of RAM?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but sometimes I am able to get the dataframe after a day running, so I guess my RAM can take it.

Comment: Maybe break it down into chunks (like 10-100K rows) and download sequentially? Then you will rule out the possibility of running out of RAM + you can restart from about the same point if it fails

Comment: The problem is in the pd.DataFrame part. The tera.execute_response part is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`DataFrame.from_query()` function](https://docs.teradata.com/r/eteIDCTX4O4IMvazRMypxQ/fuPPDmuq0MNRonTEFLuWLg) from teradata, followed by the Teradata [`.to_pandas()` method](https://docs.teradata.com/r/eteIDCTX4O4IMvazRMypxQ/h%7EcTV_5nEwCSVC6Em9oSwQ)